# Selecting item from columns in two different tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables tabeleA and tableB..

In table A, I have column(Name)
In table B, I have column(Amount)

Table A:

```
cat_id      cat_name    

 1            Man
 2            Women
 3            General
```

Table B:

```
cat_id      cat_price
 1             12
 1             18
 1             34
 1             23
 2             21
 3             31
 1             21
 3             56
```

Now in these two tables I have name and price which are linked by cat_id..

Now I want to display Name and price for that particular name and the price should be the total for particular categories......

Something like this:

TableNew:

```
cat_name    cat_price

Man         104
Woman        21
General      87
```

please help..
thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT 
tA.cat_name, SUM(tB.cat_price) AS price 
FROM TableA tA
INNER JOIN TableB tB
  ON tA.cat_id=tB.cat_id
GROUP BY tA.cat_id
```

Comment: tA????  Should it be represented as it is (or), it should be replaced by any values???

Comment: you can use anything else :) tA is an alias for TableA, so you can choose anything else, or you can simply use TableA.cat_name FROM TableA.. without tA

Comment: Strange, maybe if you change SUM(tB.cat_price) AS cat_price with SUM(tB.cat_price) AS price

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `INNER JOIN` for this:

```
SELECT
    table_a.cat_name,
    SUM(table_b.cat_price) AS price
FROM
    table_a
INNER JOIN
    table_b
ON
    table_b.cat_id = table_a.cat_id
GROUP BY
    table_a.cat_name;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.cat_name,
       sum(b.cat_price) price
  from tablea a
 inner join tableb b
    on a.cat_id = b.cat_id
 group by a.cat_name
```

[INNER JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join).

[GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) Sql Server version in absence of Wiki Sql article.

Comment: This is called [table alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp). You can use shorthand in a query to simplify it. Wherever it says a. or b. imagine it was tablea. or tableb. - longer, isn't it? Especially when you come to real table names, or self-joins...

Comment: By value you mean cat_price? Then you made a mistake adapting it to your real situation. Could you post the query _as you have typed it in_?

Answer (score 1):

```
    select T1.cat_name, T2.total 
    from TableA T1 
    NATURAL JOIN (SELECT cat_id, sum(cat_price) as total 
                  FROM TableB GROUP BY cat_id) T2
```

Comment: those are just aliases for the tables.